# Trying to run npm run dev "No entries found."

Tags: json, reactjs, parceljs

When I'm running "npm run dev" it gives me this error:
Server running at http://localhost:1234
  No entries found.
    at Bundler.bundle (/Users/igoraccebas/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/Bundler.js:275:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `parcel react/src/react.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Here is my package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "adopt-me",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An app to teach you to write React",
  "main": "react/src/App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet",
    "dev": "parcel react/src/react.html"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/btholt/complete-intro-to-react-v4.git"
  },
  "author": "Brian Holt <btholt@gmail.com>",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/btholt/complete-intro-to-react-v4/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/btholt/complete-intro-to-react-v4#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reach/router": "^1.1.1",
    "petfinder-client": "^0.0.3",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you run npm install first?

Comment: I did run npm install

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
"dev": "parcel react/src/react.html"
```

do this

```
"dev": "parcel src/react.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use main directory like that: `frontend/index.html`